# How to specify the chromedriver path which is installed inside jenkins in my cucumber code?

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I have installed Chromedriver plugin in my Jenkins, now I need to specify the path inside my code , how can I do that? When I have the driver in my local system I can do it

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Soumen\\Softwares\\chromedriver.exe");
```

but in case of Jenkins how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To completely mitigate this problem you can use this library "webdrivermanager"
to download the driver instead of having it in your local file system

and you can choose the version programmatically like that:
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("77.0.3865.40").setup();

Comment: I want to do it using Jenkins plugin, installed the plugins without any issue but now how can I specify the path in my java code that's my question.

Answer (score 0):

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\ANISH JAIN\Documents\PYTHON_PROGRAMME\chromedriver.exe")
and then use drive to do everthing

Comment: I want to use thechromedriver plugin which is installed in jenkins and build the code in jenkins, in your code you are using chromedriver which is kept in your local drive.